# how to enable emmet in vim for ejs file

Tags: vim, ejs, emmet

I wanna use [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/) on ejs files, my .vimrc config is

```
let g:user_emmet_install_global = 0
autocmd FileType html,css,ejs EmmetInstall
" redefine trigger key
let g:user_emmet_leader_key=','
let g:user_emmet_settings = {
  \  'php' : {
  \    'extends' : 'html',
  \    'filters' : 'c',
  \  },
  \  'xml' : {
  \    'extends' : 'html',
  \  },
  \  'haml' : {
  \    'extends' : 'html',
  \  },
  \  'ejs' : {
  \    'extends' : 'html',
  \  }}
```

yet it couldn't work, can anyone help?

P.S. my emmet-vim functions normally on html and css files

Comment: Try removing *ejs* from the second line.

Comment: @isAif didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it in [this way](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/#adding-custom-snippets) with web-api

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/.snippets_custom.json')), "\n"))
```

Reference: emment-vim

Comment: um, what should I write into ~/.snippets_custom.json? May you test that it really works?